# What changes have to be applied to php.ini to make php process fily types like .js?

Tags: php, file-extension

Sorry guys, I dont manage to find it out on my own: Actually, its a trivial problem: I am using Netbeans, so changing the file extension of my javascript files to .php leads to the loss of my syntax highlighting. So I'd leave the type as .js - of course this is not recognized by my php installation. What changes do I have to make, to tell php to also process the .js files in the server directory?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do this on the server end. In apache look up the php section and add a new extension to the list.

```
AddType x-httpd-php .php .js
```

But remember: every js file will now pass through the parser and incur server time and latency. Be sure this is something you really need.

Comment: Forgot to mention other servers are similar, but this is a server thing. You need to explain that when that server sends a .js file to the user it should pass it through the php interpreter before sending the result out